# Sakai Site page tools alignment

Tags: sakai

i want to customize sakai site tool  configuration like this format using layouts. but by default in sakai layout is possible by double layout or single layout. actually i need combination of both first row is double column layout and remaining single column layouts.

please tell me  is there any option to do like this.or provide me guidance how to customize .here i am inserted image i want tool alignment like this

Thanks In Advance
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjy17.png

[image: site tool alignments]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally its working i did this. Please provide any  suggestions if  required for more flexibility or any other way to do this.

***Kernel***

**Sitepage.java :-**

Add

```
public static final int LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM = 2;
```

**BaseSitepage.java:-**

Change this in

```
protected BaseSitePage(BaseSiteService siteService, Site site, String id, String title, String layout,
            boolean popup)
    {}

if (layout.equals(String.valueOf(LAYOUT_SINGLE_COL)))
        {
            m_layout = LAYOUT_SINGLE_COL;
        }
        else if (layout.equals(String.valueOf(LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL)))
        {
            m_layout = LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL;
        }
        else if(layout.equals(String.valueOf(LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM))){
            m_layout = LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM;
        }
And
protected BaseSitePage(BaseSiteService siteService, Site site, String id, String title, String layout,
            boolean popup)
    {} method
else if(layout.equals(String.valueOf(LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM))){
            m_layout = LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM;
        }
And 
public void setLayout(int layout)
    {
        if ((layout == LAYOUT_SINGLE_COL) || (layout == LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL) || (layout == LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM))
        {
            m_layout = layout;
        }
        else
            M_log.warn("setLayout(): set to invalid value: " + layout);
    }
```

**BaseSiteService.java:-**

```
public String[] getLayoutNames()
    {
        String[] rv = new String[3];
        rv[0] = rb.getString("sitpag.lay_sngl");
        rv[1] = rb.getString("sitpag.lay_dbl");
        rv[2] = rb.getString("sitpag.lay_cust1");
            return rv;  }
```

***Portal:-***

Comment following code in the method

```
 public void includePage(PortalRenderContext rcontext, HttpServletResponse res,
            HttpServletRequest req, Session session, SitePage page,
            String toolContextPath, String wrapperClass) throws IOException
    {
rcontext.put("pageColumnLayout", (page.getLayout()==SitePage.LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL) ? "col1of2": "col1");
```

and  replace the code

```
if(page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL){
                rcontext.put("pageColumnLayout","col1of2");
                
    }
else if(page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM){
        rcontext.put("pageColumnLayout","SingleDouble");
    }
else{
    rcontext.put("pageColumnLayout","col1");
}
```

And change

```
rcontext.put("pageTwoColumn", Boolean
                    .valueOf(page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL || page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM));

And
// do the second column if needed
            if (page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL ||page.getLayout() == SitePage.LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM)
```

***Site Manage:-***

**SiteAction.java**

Add custom layout to following method 8990 line

```
private void addSynopticTool(SitePage page, String toolId,
            String toolTitle, String layoutHint) {

        if (page.getContainingSite() != null) {
            if (page.getLayout() != SitePage.LAYOUT_SINGLE_COL || page.getLayout() != SitePage.LAYOUT_MY_CUSTOM|| !page.getContainingSite().isCustomPageOrdered() ) {
                page.setLayout(SitePage.LAYOUT_DOUBLE_COL);
            }
        }
}
```

***OSP  Tool***

**XSltcharon portal:-**

**XsltrenderContext.java:-**

Comment the following

```
/*pageElement.setAttribute("layout", (context.get("pageColumnLayout")
                    .equals("col1")) ? "0" : "1");*/
```

And replace with

```
String selectedLayout="0";
            //context.put("pageColumnLayout","SingleDouble");
            
            if(context.get("pageColumnLayout").equals("col1of2")){
                selectedLayout="1";
            }
            else if(context.get("pageColumnLayout").equals("SingleDouble")){
                selectedLayout="2";
            }
            else{
                selectedLayout="0";
                }
```

And add following statements in if (selected)

```
if(context.get("pageColumnLayout").equals("SingleDouble")){
        
                Element column3 = doc.createElement("column");
                Element column4 = doc.createElement("column");
                Element column5 = doc.createElement("column");
                column3.setAttribute("index","3");
                column4.setAttribute("index","4");
                column5.setAttribute("index","5");
                
                LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();
                LinkedList l2=new LinkedList();
                LinkedList all=new LinkedList();
                List column0Tools=(List)context.get("pageColumn0Tools");
List column1Tools=(List)context.get("pageColumn1Tools");
                
    if(column0Tools !=null){
        l1.add(column0Tools.get(0));
                    column3.appendChild(createColumnToolsXml(doc,l1, page));
            column0Tools.remove(0);
            if(column0Tools !=null)
{
                all.addAll(column0Tools);               
    
                }
            columns.appendChild(column3);
            if(column1Tools !=null && column1Tools.size()>0 )
{   l2.add(column1Tools.get(0));                    column4.appendChild(createColumnToolsXml(doc,l2, page));
                    column1Tools.remove(0);
                    if(column1Tools !=null){
                    all.addAll(column1Tools);
                    }
                
                }
                columns.appendChild(column4);
                    if(all !=null){
                    column5.appendChild(createColumnToolsXml(doc,all, page));
                    }
                    columns.appendChild(column5);               
                
                    
                    
            }
```

***Osp-Portal***

**osp-portal.xsl:-**

Add the following into portal.xslt and osp-portal.xsl

```
<!--
   ===============match single and Double============
   process a selected page with two column layouts
   param:content - "true" or "false" if rendering tool content or tool list
   =========================================================
   -->
<xsl:template match="page[@layout='2' and @selected='true']">
      <xsl:param name="content"/>
      <xsl:if test="$content='true'">
         <xsl:call-template name="page-content-custom">
            <xsl:with-param name="page" select="."/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$content='false'">
         <li>
            <a accesskey="1" class="selected" href="#">
               <xsl:attribute name="accesskey">
                  <xsl:value-of select="../../@order"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>
         </li>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>


<!--Custom Sarath  -->

<xsl:template name="page-content-custom">
        <xsl:param name="page" />
    <h1 class="skip">
    <xsl:value-of select="$externalized/entry[@key='sit.contentshead']" />
    </h1>
    <a id="tocontent" class="skip" name="tocontent"></a>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="col1of2">
        <div class="portlet">
        <p class="pageId">$page</p>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$page/columns/column[@index='3']/tools/tool">
                        <xsl:call-template name="tool">
                            <xsl:with-param name="tool" select="." />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col2of2">
                <div class="portlet">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$page/columns/column[@index='4']/tools/tool">
                        <xsl:call-template name="tool">
                            <xsl:with-param name="tool" select="." />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="col1">
                <div class="portlet">

                    <xsl:for-each select="$page/columns/column[@index='5']/tools/tool">
                        <xsl:call-template name="tool">
                            <xsl:with-param name="tool" select="." />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

in **Portal.css** file

```
#col1_new{
    padding-right: .0em;
clear:both;
}
#col1of2_new{
    width: 51%;
    */width: 48%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
}

#col2of2_new{
    width: 48%;
    */width: 48%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can work this up into a patch and submit it to https://jira.sakaiproject.org?